# How to write python command line arguments in boto3 to execute on EC2 Instance (SSM)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, command-line-arguments, boto3

```
import boto3

def execute_commands_on_linux_instances(client, commands, instance_ids):
resp = client.send_command(
    DocumentName="AWS-RunShellScript", # One of AWS' preconfigured documents
    Parameters={'commands': commands},
    InstanceIds=instance_ids

ssm_client = boto3.client('ssm', region_name = 'us-west-2')
commands = ["python test.py arg1 arg2 arg3"]
instance_ids = ["i-xxxxxxxxxx"]
execute_commands_on_linux_instances(ssm_client, commands, instance_ids)
```

**Anyone know how to pass python command line arguments into Boto3 SSM client?**

I'm able to write the command line argument within the EC2 instance as

```
python test.py arg1 arg2 arg3
```

The command above works.

**However executing the argument within SSM, it says the python file is not found.**

I re-checked the directory and it seems that when I type -ls it retrieves a list of Amazon functions instead of a list of files. 
Anyone know how to re-write this command line argument or know any documentation to write this within the boto3.client? Much appreciated.

Comment: Lots of potential errors here; what is the specific error? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/APIReference/API_SendCommand.html

Comment: @ChrisPollard, Hey Chris, thanks for the help. It says py file is missing or not found. I did an ls within run command to see what the dir looks like, and they all point to base functions "[ 2to3 2to3-2.7 2to3-3.5 aa-enabled acpi_listen" 
versus ls in the instance which outputs the list of files.

Comment: Where is `test.py` located in the filesystem of your instance?

Comment: Hi @OluwafemiSule, the issue has been fixed. How can I close this?

Comment: Hi @JonathanTHo, if you feel the SO community will benefit in the long run from an answer, you can submit one. Otherwise, feel free to delete your question